# Background texture pattern removal before crack detection with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect cracks on a moving conveyor belt. Below is an example:

[image: crack on light pattern belt]

For the above image, I could use GaussianBlur followed by a Canny and then findContour to detect the crack. However in other cases, I need to detect the crack on belt with heavy patterns. For example, below is the "heavy pattern" belt with no crack. (Sorry I couldn't find one with crack on this type of belt).

[image: no crack on belt with heavy pattern]

My old method doesn't work very well on this type of belt. I can remove the belt pattern if I use a larger kernel for GaussianBlur. But it also reduce/remove the crack.

Update: here is another blob type crack image.

[image: another crack on light pattern belt]

I try to detect it with SimpleBlobDetector. But on the heavy pattern belt, it gives a lot of false positive. Any suggestions on how to detect blob like that on a patterned belt?

Update 2:

I followed the suggestion from @nathancy on the bilateralFilter:

```
min_area = 400
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 125, 125)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,2)
canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 120, 255, 1)
```

The dilated image are as below.

[image: dilated image 1]
[image: dilated image 2]
[image: dilated image 3]

For these particular pictures, I can do a "min_area = 400" to distinguish between the cracks and patterns. However the larger kernel blur also scrubs part of the cracks away together with the patterns. So I'd expect the min_area selection won't be very stable in the more complex real environment (i.e. different light conditions, etc.). I have a question, since the pattern is always +-45 degrees. Is there any filter can help to remove the patterns in these directions?

Comment: The crack is an horizontal line so you code use gradient filter to find an horizontal picture, then Hough transform to find all the line on it, and take the one with lowest angle

Comment: @lhgiang149 thanks for your quick reply. The crack in the example picture is horizontal. However I want to detect all the possible cracks in real life, which could be in any direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a potential solution

- Convert image to grayscale and median blur
- Adaptive threshold
- Canny edge detection
- Morphological transformations to clean up noise
- Dilate to enhance contours
- Find contours
- Iterate through contours and filter using minimum threshold area

---

Here's the results

[image]

One potential preprocessing step would be to remove the dark sections before detecting cracks since it screws up the median blur and adaptive threshold. For instance, if you were able to remove the black sections on the last image, you would get this result.

[image]

Potential optimizations would be to play with the median blur as this helps to smooth out the pattern on the belt. You could also adjust the minimum threshold area to control the size of the detected crack

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')

blur = cv2.medianBlur(image, 7)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,3)

canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 120, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
dilate = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 3000
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It works pretty well on the first and third images (cracks on light pattern belt). But I get something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/OIeznO7) on the second image. Would you please shed some light on how to remove the heavy pattern on the second image?

Comment: You could try increasing the blur or trying a different blur filter like [`cv2.bilateralFilter()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) to keep edges sharp. The 2nd image is difficult since the crack blends in with the pattern